# Connecting a MS Access (.mdb) Database to a MVC3 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ms-access

Right, I have been tasked with developing a new application in MVC3 that unfortunately has to integrate very slightly with a classic asp web site. This won't be forever as the old site will get an update at some point, but not yet. In the mean time however the new MVC3 application will need a little bit of access to the database for the old site, which is a old MS Access .mdb whereas the new  app will be using sql server 2008.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me some examples of how to connect to the access db, aswell as how to execute sql queries (i am fine writing the sql, just got no idea how to execute against the database from my mvc3 app).

thanks in advance

EDIT: I've not got much experience with the old site, but it appears to use the JET adaptor if  that helps! ;-)

Comment: I feel your pain!! Access. Ugh! Look over at connectionstrings.com and there's a connection string there for connecting to an access db. It's straightforward.. but it'll be sloooooww once more than 5 people start hitting it at the same time

Comment: For actually accessing the db, you can access it with the Microsoft Data Access Application block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string connectionString = Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
public void InsertRow(string connectionString, string insertSQL)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // The insertSQL string contains a SQL statement that
        // inserts a new row in the source table.
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(insertSQL);

        // Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
        command.Connection = connection;

        // Open the connection and execute the insert command.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the
        // code exits the using block.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question requires an answer too extensive to be given in detail
I will give you a check list of things and class to research

- Define the connection string used to reach your database [[see
  here]](http://www.connectionstrings.com)
- Create and open the [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx)
- Define your [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) and the command text to be executed
- Create and use an [OleDbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to read your data line by line
- Create and use an [OleDbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to read your data and load a
  DataSet or DataTable

Now don't forget to close your connection and use parametrized query